How to get docker work on qemu shared folders?
I have a copied virtual machine with a qcow2 system image and a huge data folder. There are a few systems like gitlab/mysql etc. running in docker inside the vm, and I would like to run the vm locally.
I have tried to boot the qcow2 image, mount the data folder as a disk by adding -virtfs local,path=/home/leetom/gitdata,mount_tag=gitdata,security_model=passthrough,id=gitdata to the starting command and use mount -t 9p -o trans=virtio,version=9p2000.L gitdata /opt to mount in the vm.
The vm booted successfully, and the data folder was successfully mounted. However, dockerd failed to startup, saying failed to start daemon: error while opening volume store metadata database: invalid argument. I read that docker could not run on shared folders, so I copied all docker containers files from data folder (shared folder) to the qcow2 system image. After that dockerd could start, but gitlab container failed to startup. The gitlab container use files from the data folder which is bond to the container. The error message is "error":"listen unix /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/socket: bind: no such device or address", and I tried to create unix domain socket with nc, and failed if the destination is located inside the shared folder.
I think it should work if I copy all files in the shared folder to a new qcow2 image and mount it in the vm, but it may take days.
Are there any other way to get things work? I am also curious about why things won't work, and why unix domain sockets could not be created.
I thought docker is running things in aufs or overlay2, and it should work as long as it can write to the underlying file system.
